# Chevy C2 brokes its valves when the timing belt is broken?

Tags: timing-belt, chevrolet

The [Chevy C2](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opel_Corsa#Chevy_C2) is and Opel Corsa designed by General Motors México.

The version I own  is model 2007 and its gear transmision is automatic.
I Bought this car used and I send it to the mechanic yo change its timing belt. But about 2.500 KM it get broken.

Why could this happen? I have read that when this belt is broken the car could have several damage like broke its valves, but that if depends of the design of the motor.

In this kind of motor what damage could have happened?

Thank in advace.

Answer (score 4):

If the engine is a non-interference design, you're fine.  If it's an interference design, you've probably got engine damage from the valves being open at the wrong time and being struck by the pistons.  To find out which type you have, you need to figure out which engine you have.  Search for 'gm VIN decoder' and enter your [VIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_Identification_Number).  Once you know the specific engine you have, you can see if you can find out if it's interference or non-interference.